# R-How to group specific column value and creating new list of column value dynamically

Tags: r

i have data frame like below ,i need to group specific column and create new list of column by column value.

My data frame

```
  Domain      Process      Name            value1          value2  

        ML          First       Peter             T1               45
        ML          First       Peter             FT               34
        ML          First       Peter             T1               34
        ML          First       Jhon              LL               11
        ML          First       Jhon              LL               11
        ML          Second      Peter             IO               22
        ML          Second      Peter             IO               33
        ML          Second      Peter             IO               33
        ML          four        Peter             IO               33
```

my expected data frame.

```
Domain    Process      Name        column                listofvalues             

ML         First      Peter          value1               list(info1 = "T1", "Count"="2",list(info2 = "FT", "Count"="1"))
ML         First      Peter          value2               list(info1 = "45", "Count"="1",list(info2 ="34", "Count"="2"))
ML         First      Jhon           value1               list(info1 = "LL", "Count"="2") 
ML         First      Jhon           value2               list(info1 = "11", "Count"="2")            
ML         Second     Peter          value1               list(info1 = "IO", "Count"="3")
ML         Second     Peter          value2               list(info1 = "22", "Count"="1",list(info2 ="33", "Count"="2"))
ML         four       Peter          value1               list(info1 = "IO", "Count"="1")
ML
```

dput Data.

```
structure(list(Domain = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "ML", class = "factor"), Process = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("First", "four", 
"Second"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jhon", "Peter"), class = "factor"), 
    value1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FT", 
    "IO", "LL", "T1"), class = "factor"), value2 = structure(c(5L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("11", "22", "33", 
    "34", "45"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Domain", "Process", 
"Name", "value1", "value2"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gather` and `nest` from `tidyr` to accomplish your aim:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  gather(key, value, -c(Domain, Process, Name)) %>%
  group_by(Domain, Process, Name, key, value) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  nest(key, value, count, .key = "listofvalues")

df

# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#     Domain Process  Name    key     listofvalues
#      <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>           <list>
#   1     ML   First  Jhon value1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   2     ML   First  Jhon value2 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   3     ML   First Peter value1 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#   4     ML   First Peter value2 <tibble [2 x 2]>
#   5     ML    four Peter value1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   6     ML    four Peter value2 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   7     ML  Second Peter value1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
#   8     ML  Second Peter value2 <tibble [2 x 2]>

df$listofvalues[[3]]

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   value count
#   <chr> <int>
# 1    FT     1
# 2    T1     2
```

if you are determined to `spread` the nested column, you can add

```
mutate(listofvalues = purrr::map(listofvalues, spread, value, count))
```

to the pipe chain, however, I don't recommend that unless it is really necessary. Partly because you have numeric values that would become names.

```
df$listofvalues[[4]]

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#    `34`  `45`
# * <int> <int>
# 1     2     1
```

Comment: ,i have one more doubt please help me  how to calculate score instead count.